# Using third level sub-menu to qualify second level menu

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, sql-server

I have 3 dropdowns Category, Category Type, and CategoryType-Style.  All 3 are populated from a database.

Category Type is populated based on the selection made in the Category dropdown.

I would like for CategoryType-Style to be populated based on the selection made in Category Type, and thereby giving options to select as CategoryType-Style.

I have Category and Category Type working fine, but cannot get the CategoryType-Style portion correct.  Any help would be appreciated. The CSS code is as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ddlCategory.DataSource = GetData("spGetCategory", null);
            ddlCategory.DataBind();

            ListItem liCategory = new ListItem("Select A Category", "-1");
            ddlCategory.Items.Insert(0, liCategory);

            ListItem liCategoryType = new ListItem("Select A Category Type", "-1");
            ddlCategoryType.Items.Insert(0, liCategoryType);

            ddlCategoryType.Enabled = false;


            ListItem liStyle = new ListItem("Select A Style", "-1");
            ddlStyle.Items.Insert(0, liStyle);

            ddlStyle.Enabled = false;
 }


protected void ddlCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlCategory.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            ddlCategoryType.SelectedIndex = 0;
            ddlCategoryType.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ddlCategoryType.Enabled = true;
            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@CategoryID", ddlCategory.SelectedValue);
            DataSet DS = GetData("spGetCategoryTypeByCategoryID", parameter);

            ddlCategoryType.DataSource = DS;
            ddlCategoryType.DataBind();

            ListItem liCategoryType = new ListItem("Select A Category Type", "-1");
            ddlCategoryType.Items.Insert(0, liCategoryType);
        }

        if (ddlCategoryType.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            ddlStyle.SelectedIndex = 0;
            ddlStyle.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ddlStyle.Enabled = true;
            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@CategoryTypeID", ddlCategoryType.SelectedValue);
            DataSet DS = GetData("spGetStyleByCategoryTypeID", parameter);

            ddlStyle.DataSource = DS;
            ddlStyle.DataBind();

            ListItem liStyle = new ListItem("Select A Style", "-1");
            ddlStyle.Items.Insert(0, liStyle);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried an IndexChanged just for CategoryType and it did not work either.  The code: protected void ddlCategoryType_SelectedIndexedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlCategoryType.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            ddlStyle.SelectedIndex = 0;
            ddlStyle.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ddlStyle.Enabled = true;
            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("CategoryTypeID", ddlCategoryType.SelectedValue);
            DataSet DS = GetData("spGetStyleByCategoryTypeID", parameter);

```
        ddlStyle.DataSource = DS;
        ddlStyle.DataBind();

        ListItem liStyle = new ListItem("Select A Style", "-1");
        ddlStyle.Items.Insert(0, liStyle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely you need a ddlCategoryType_SelectedIndexChanged to handle populating the style ddl?

Comment: Darren, I tried see the above edit.  I had also tried as you suggested.  I think because of the CategoryType being tied to the Category, a straight IndexChanged will not work.